ChromeDriver on Ubuntu/Linux Not working - Laravel Dusk not Working
After 5 hours of banging my head I can not figure this out. I have tried many things that fixed other peoples issues, when I run chromedriver-linux binary in /vendor/laravel/dusk/bin
I get:
/home/forge/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

I have tried downloading different versions, all give the same error.
When I run the php artisan dusk, command I get:
PHPUnit 9.6.20 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

RE                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/home/forge/www/.phpunit.result.cache): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/forge/www/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/DefaultTestResultCache.php on line 146

Warning: file_put_contents(/home/forge/www/.phpunit.result.cache): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/forge/www/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/DefaultTestResultCache.php on line 146


Time: 00:01.213, Memory: 16.00 MB

There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Browser\Microsite\ReviewVerification::testClipboard
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\Internal\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"browserName":"chrome","goog:chromeOptions":{"args":["--window-size=1920,1080","--disable-search-engine-choice-screen","--disable-gpu","--headless","--no-sandbox","--verbose"]}}]},"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","goog:chromeOptions":{"args":["--window-size=1920,1080","--disable-search-engine-choice-screen","--disable-gpu","--headless","--no-sandbox","--verbose"]}}}

Failed to connect to localhost port 9515 after 0 ms: Connection refused

/home/forge/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Exception/Internal/WebDriverCurlException.php:20
/home/forge/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:328
/home/forge/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:129
/home/forge/www/tests/DuskTestCase.php:100
/home/forge/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:220
/home/forge/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:247
/home/forge/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:219
/home/forge/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:99
/home/forge/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:67
/home/forge/www/tests/DuskTestCase.php:37

--

There was 1 risky test:

1) Tests\Browser\Microsite\ReviewVerification::testExample
This test did not perform any assertions

/home/forge/www/tests/Browser/Microsite/ReviewVerification.php:26

ERRORS!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1, Risky: 1.

I have even created a custom dusk command that runs dusk between Xvfb running to no avail
public function handle()
    {

        $xvfb = (new Process(['/usr/bin/Xvfb', '-ac', ':0', '-screen', '0', '1280x1024x16']))
            ->setTimeout(null);

        $xvfb->start();

        try {
            parent::handle();
        } finally {
            $xvfb->stop();
        }

        return;


        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }

When I do this I get the error:
php artisan dusk++:run
  The "pest" option does not exist.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I got it working with a lot of trial error and swapping versions, you basically have to utilize the different packages available, in my case on Ubuntu for the chrome browser there are different packages with completely different names that are all Google Chrome but with different versions available:
Your Chrome Options:
1.apt-get package: chromium
2-apt-get package: chromium-browser
3-apt-get package: google-chrome
4-apt-get package: google-chrome-stable
Your Chrome Driver Options:
1-npm package:chromedriver
2-php artisan dusk:install:chrome-driver (downloads from Google binaries)
3-apt-get install chromium-chromedriver
4-3rd party packages
You Laravel Dusk Option:
All the versions available for you php version and composer/laravel dependencies
Basically I swapped these in and out over and over for hour until I got a

Google "chromium" package that was 128
A ChromeDriver was 128 (installed by npm install --global that then I swapped for the one in the vendor folder that dusk uses)
It still did not work until I did: "apt-get purge google-chrome" which was version 107 and it allow it to not hijack the chrome launch from dusk, and by deleting that it started working.

